# Is it more efficient to create new LayerGroups or change sources of existing layers in the LayerGroup?

Tags: openlayers

I would like to change data layers based on a button click, and the current way I'm doing it is with `map.setLayerGroup(group)`. The following is an example from my project of switching base tiles based on radio button input, where `tilesList` is a list of `ol.layer.Tile` objects:

```
    input.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const layers = [tiles.tilesList[i]].concat(dataLayers);
        const group = new ol.layer.Group({
            layers: layers,
        });
        map.setLayerGroup(group);
    });
```

In the above case I'm creating a new `LayerGroup` each time I switch tiles, but currently I'm trying to implement layers that have a LOT of data on them. I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to keep doing it this way or to edit the sources of already existing tiles?

Comment: There are several questions in this question. GIS SE site prefers focused question where there is only one question per question. Please edit your question and limit it to one focused question, otherwise it'll be most probably closed as needing more focus. And seeking "best way" leads to opinionated questions, which as again against GIS SE site policy, so avoid using this formulation.

Comment: @TomazicM Edited! Although I could only find one other post about this topic and it seems to be outdated.

Comment: Is individual list of tiles `tiles.tilesList[i]` constant after initialization or it can change later?

Comment: @TomazicM It should remain constant at this point in the project.

Comment: But `dataLayers` are changing, I suppose?

Comment: @TomazicM Yep! They are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the optimal solution would be to create layer group only once and then upon change set layers of this group with the `.setLayers` method.

Since this method expects `ol.Collection` as input, layer collection has to be created from layer array. This in no way affects performance, since as docs say that collection is just *"an expanded version of standard JS Array, adding convenience methods for manipulation"*.

```
const group = new ol.layer.Group();
map.setLayerGroup(group);

input.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const layerCollection = new ol.Collection([tiles.tilesList[i]].concat(dataLayers));
  group.setLayers(layerCollection);
  });
});
```

Comment: `group.setLayers()` only seems to work if it's passed a `ol.Collection` object, so the layers array would have to be passed into a collection object before into the `setLayers()` function, do you know if this affects the efficiency much?

Comment: For me it returns an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function`. I put the layers in a Collection and it works. It also says in the documentation that `setLayers()` takes a Collection. Can you help or not?

Comment: You are right, see modified answer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I was snarky, it felt like you were being kind of dismissive.